# Take a picture and save it without the gallery

Tags: android, image, save, android-gallery

In my app im taking picture and saving to the sqlite to here everything is ok. After i take photo its also saving in to the Gallery...Any idea how to do it without the save picture to the galery ? Im taking picture with the bellow code.

```
String[] perms = {"android.permission.CAMERA"};

                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(HataListDetayActivity.this,
                        Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(HataListDetayActivity.this,
                            perms, 1

                    );
                }
                Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 4);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case two option

1) you can delete photo if not needed

2) you can create your folder and inside create `.nomedia` file

```
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File myFolder = new File(sdcard.getAbsolutePath() + "/mymir/");
    if(!myFolder.exists())
    {
        File noMedia = new File(myFolder.getAbsolutePath() + "/.nomedia");
        noMedia.mkdirs();
        noMedia.createNewFile();
    }

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Nice. Correct. But i think OP ment with 'not visible in the gallery' 'not another copy on the file system' . As storage place will run out.